# A Dull Dull Word

Tags: riddle, word

Here is your riddle for the day!

I am a five letter word.

> With five I'm made of three
>
> With four I might give a raise
>
> With three I'm a good friend
>
> With two I like to react

What word am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you

> Brown?

> With two I like to react

> Br, or Bromine, is highly reactive.

> With three I'm a good friend

> A Bro is a good friend.

> With four I might give a raise

> A Brow might be raised ("raised eyebrows")

> With five I'm made of three

> Brown as a color could be said to be made of the three primary colors (red, blue, yellow): mixing all creates brown.

Title:

> Brown could be said to be a dull color